# Html.fromHtml for CDATA tag and XML tag

Tags: android, html, eclipse, textview

I am trying to use this code to change the text of my textview from html to normal text.

```
    description.setText(Html.fromHtml(EventRss.desc));
```

[image: android]

for example, changing the a href code to just link and clickable and then brings me to the url.

The code that I had grabbed consist of a xml description tag and CDATA tag,

whenever I use the Html.fromHTML code, only the description tag and
 CDATA is removed. The p , a href code is still there...

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: have you tried description.setText(Html.fromHtml((EventRss.desc).toString()));

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, I just tried and the result is still same as the screenshot I had posted.

Comment: Can you dump the XML you are passing to `Html#fromHtml()` verbatim in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
description(Html.fromHtml(htmlString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Here is a list of supported tags http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, I tried and it doesn't work.

yup i had read it before and <p> and <a> tag is supported